# Deserialize NSString into [NSDate distantPast]

Tags: objective-c

I have an [NSDate distantPast] object sent to an API, serialized via [date description].  When it is retrieved, it returns the exact same string.  However, when I convert the string back to an NSDate object, instead of becoming an [NSDate distantPast] date, it returns nil.  The code below serializes other dates perfectly fine:

```
NSString *dateString = [[NSDate distantPast] description];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z";
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

How can I properly serialize / deserialize any NSDate object without needing to apply a special case for [NSDate distantPast]?

Comment: @HotLicks is 33% right: (1) right that description is what is mixing you up, (2) not right that distantPast is a special case relative to formatting, (3) not right that there's any problem shipping code that relies on description (except regarding (1)).

Comment: @danh - In general, the `description` method of a class is not defined to produce a consistent representation, but it can change at the whim of Apple.  (Never mind that *anything* can change at Apple's whim -- they'd be even less sorry about changing `description`.)

Comment: @HotLicks is there an apple statement somewhere that says that description is more apt to change than other part of the public sdk?  Anyway, within a given version of the sds, it should be perfectly fine.  (I reply here not so much argumentatively, but hopefully, since I have shipped code that relies, for example, on description of an NSNumber).

Comment: I know that `description` has changed ever so slightly for NSDate since I first started working with iOS about 5 years ago.  I've never found the actual statement, but it is, at the very least, "common knowledge".

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reverse engineer the format relied upon by `description`, just use the same format string to avoid ambiguity...

```
NSString *dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = dateFormat;

NSDate *date = [NSDate distantPast];  // or any NSDate
NSString *dateAsString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate distantPast]];

// then later, using the same formatter or, if that one has been released, a new
// one built with the same format string ...

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = dateFormat;

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateAsString];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

**EDIT** - To save an NSDate with full resolution, (and not relying on NSCoding) use its time interval...

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate distantPast];

NSTimeInterval i = [date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
NSNumber *interval = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:i];

// serialize interval however you wish... NSCoding, as a string, etc. to
// reconstitute a date, get interval from however it was saved, then ...
NSDate *distantPast = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:[interval doubleValue]];

if ([distantPast isEqualToDate:[NSDate distantPast]]) {  // this will be true
}
```

Again, nothing special about distantPast, here.  Its just an old date.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but it still doesn't serialize back to an [NSDate distantPast] object.  If you run [date isEqualToDate:[NSDate distantPast]] it returns false.

Comment: @Justin - date formatter makes NSDate presentable to humans, losing resolution in the process.  To serialize NSDates with high fidelity, you can rely on the fact that NSDate is NSCoding compliant, or represent as a boxed time interval.  Please see edit...